# How to deploy Django with SciPy on Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, numpy, scipy, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Since `pip install -r requirements.txt` not works well since it might compile `scipy` before `numpy` and get an error.

`requirements.txt` like following:

```
pip==8.0.3
Django==1.9.0
psycopg2==2.6.1
wheel==0.24.0
requests
numpy==1.7.2
scipy==0.15.1
```

Anyway, I tried to use `.ebextensions/xxx.config` to solve this problem, so I removed `scipy` from the list above and added it to the config file as the following:

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    gcc: []
    gcc-c++: []
    gcc-gfortran: []
    readline-devel: []
    postgresql94-devel: []
    atlas: []
    blas: []
    lapack-devel: []
    blas-devel: []
    atlas-devel: []
  commands:
    00-prep-environment:
      command: "scripts/scipy.sh"
```

and `scipy.sh` is

```
/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install scipy
/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install Pillow
/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip freeze
```

However this is still not working and I got `scipy not found` error when I do `import scipy` in my Django code.I tried with many solutions by others but not works for me. Anyone has experience on how to deploy Django with SciPy on Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk? Thank you!

Comment: What error message do you get? Have you installed pip install cython?